# Delphi to Microsoft PowerPoint Integration... Setting Bold attribute

Tags: vba, delphi, com, ms-office, powerpoint

Delphi Seattle, PPT 2013.

I am using Delphi to programatically build a PPT deck.  I have a PPT template I am using.  I extract a PPT file that is embedded in the executable as a resource, I start PPT, open the file, go to a slide, and populate the content. The issue I am currently fighting has to do with font attributes.  I have a textframe.  I want to write various lines to that textframe separated by CR/LF.  PPT shows these are separate bullets which is what I want. The first word of each line is a category so I want JUST THAT WORD in bold.  It should end up looking like this...

- **Category1** - product1, product2
- **Category2** - product3, product4

In code, I add the first line to the textframe, and then say... from Characters 1-9 set it bold.  Now add to the textframe the 2nd line, and set from characters 20 through the next 9 characters to bold... etc.  This is a 4 line operation.  Add 1st line, set bold, add second line, set bold.  Lines 1 and 2 work, but as soon as I add the 2nd line of text, EVERYTHING goes bold.  If I change order of my code, to add line 1, add line 2, set first substring bold, set 2nd substring bold, that will work, but that is more difficult based on how I am doing various other things.

I have tried add line 1, set characters 1 through 9 bold, SET CHARACTER 10 NOT BOLD, now add line 2... but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here is a code snippet.

```
uses ... Office2000, msppt2000;

    var
  lFinalDeck: PowerPointPresentation;
  lApplication: PowerPointApplication;
  sl: _Slide;
  sh1 : Shape;
  FoundIt : Boolean;
  i : Integer;
  CRLF : String;
  PPTFileName : String;
begin

lApplication := CoPowerPointApplication.Create;
...
// Open File
lFinalDeck := lApplication.Presentations.Open(PPTFileName, msoFalse, msoFalse, msoFalse);
// The second parameter specifies whether the presentation should be opened in read-only mode.
// If the third parameter is True, an untitled copy of the file is made.
// The last parameter specifies whether the opened presentation should be visible.

 // Get a handle to my slide and go to it.
 sl := lFinalDeck.Slides.Item(2);
 sl.Select;

 FoundIt := False;
 CRLF := #13#10;

 // Now look for the textframe that has the TEXT 'TEXTBOX1'
 for i := 1 to sl.Shapes.Count  do
    begin
    sh1 := sl.Shapes.Item(i);
    if sh1.HasTextFrame = msoTrue then
      if sh1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = 'TEXTBOX1' then
      begin
       FoundIt := True;
       sh1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text := '';
       Break;
      end;
    end; 

    // Put data in the textframe, setting first 5 characters of each line bold
    sh1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text := '1234567890' + CRLF;
    sh1.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1,5).Font.Bold := msoTrue;


    sh1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text := sh1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text + 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP' + CRLF;
    sh1.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(13,5).Font.Bold := msoTrue;
end;
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It is how Powerpoint, and office programs in general behave, I believe. When you add a new paragraph it assumes the font of the previous paragraph, which is a bit of a pain sometimes, even when you are doing it manually. The only way I can suggest to do it is to set the text selection where you plan to insert your new para and set the font explicitly to bold off, or to add your selection and set bold off, perhaps in a separate procedure to simplify things when you are doing it multiple times.

Comment: `so I want JUST THAT WORD in bold` - since you work with Microsoft Office then there is one universal answer to almost all those questions: just read how the office do it. Start "Recording Visual Basic Macro". Then select the word and make it bold and de-select it. Then "Stop recording Macro". Then open Macro's manager, find your new Macro and enter into its editor. You would see Visual Basic code that does it. Translate it from Basic to Pascal. PS. I do not know where those Macro-related commands are hid in Office 2013. If not found try Classic Menu for Office trial

Comment: Record Macro capability is in MOST Office products, but not in Powerpoint.  Powerpoint 2007 was the last version that had it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of approaching it in VBA, which should give you enough to go on in converting to Delphi or others.

A shape's TextFrame.TextRange represents the entire string of text in the shape.
You can iterate through its .Paragraphs collection to access each individual paragraph (essentially, every string of text terminated by a CRLF).
Each Paragraph has a Words collection and by referencing the first word you can turn just that word bold.
If you need instead to make a certain number of characters bold, use

```
Set oRng = .Paragraphs(x).Characters(1, 12) ' 12 chars
```

instead of

```
Set oRng = .Paragraphs(x).Words(1)
```

below:

```
Sub BoldFirstWord(oSh As Shape)
' Bold the first word of each paragraph in the shape

    Dim x As Long
    Dim oRng as TextRange

    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange

        For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count

            Set oRng = .Paragraphs(x).Words(1)
            oRng.Font.Bold = True

        Next

    End With

End Sub

' To test the above, select the text shape
' you want to work with and run this:
Sub TestBFW()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    Call BoldFirstWord(oSh)
End Sub
```